# Filter with different levels of depth

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a menu with this structure

```
item1
item2
     childrenOfItem2
                    childrenOfchildren1
                    childrenOfchildren2
                    HELLOchildrenOfchildren3
     childrenOfItem2
     childrenOfItem2
HELLOitem3
item4
     childrenOfItem4
     HELLOchildrenOfItem4
item5
     childrenOfItem5
```

So, Id' like to get all the items that have the word "HELLO" and what I'm doing is a loop over the first items, then, another loop and then another loop, is there any other way of doing it? Since let's say that if we add another level of depth in the menu it will not work,

Thank you!

Edited: adding JS for better understanding

```
const matchName = (item, word) =>
  item?.title?.toLowerCase()?.includes(word?.toLowerCase());

const filter = (word = "", arr = []) => {
  const listOfItems = [];
  arr.forEach((item) => {
    if (matchName(item, word)) {
      listOfItems.push(item);
    } else if (item?.children?.length > 0) {
      const newSubItem = [];
      item.children.forEach((subItem) => {
        if (matchName(subItem, word)) {
          newSubItem.push(subItem);
        } else if (subItem?.children?.length > 0) {
          const newSubSubItems = [];
          subItem.children.forEach((subsubItem) => {
            if (matchName(subsubItem, word)) {
              newSubSubItems.push(subsubItem);
            }
          });
          if (newSubSubItems?.length > 0) {
            newSubItem.push({ ...subItem, children: newSubSubItems });
          }
        }
      });
      if (newSubItem?.length > 0) {
        listOfItems.push({ ...item, children: newSubItem });
      }
    }
  });
  return listOfItems;
};
```

Sample of arr received as parameter in the fnc:

```
const list = [
  {
    id: "41",
    title: "sample",
    children: [
      {
        id: "42",
        title: "sample",

        children: [
          {
            id: "43",
            title: "sample",

            children: [],
          },
          {
            id: "44",
            title: "sample",

            children: [],
          },
          {
            id: "45",
            title: "sample",

            children: [],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: "46",
        title: "sample",
        children: [
          {
            id: "47",
            title: "sample",

            children: [],
          },
          {
            id: "48",
            title: "sample",

            children: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "29",
    title: "sample",

    children: [
      {
        id: "30",
        title: "sample",

        children: [],
      },
      {
        id: "49",
        title: "sample",

        children: [],
      },
      {
        id: "31",
        title: "sample",

        children: [],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Comment: please add raw data as javascript literal and your code, you tried along with the wanted result.

Comment: added :) I thought it would be easier to understand without the JS

Comment: please add the data as well. and result.

Comment: I added an small sample, the word will be the word the user introduces, and as result, the code I put works I wanted to enhance it since I'm pretty sure that's not the best way of doing it

Comment: what is the wanted result from given data?

Comment: You may want to flatten your tree before filtering 
 assuming the hierarchy has no bearing on the end-result https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#flattenDeep

Comment: On this case, since I put sample as name of all the items, if the user search by let's say "ample" all data will be returned as an array (Same as the list) if the user search for "qwerty" it will not match any title, so an empty array is returned

Comment: Since it's a filter for a menu I still need to know which is the parent, if I flat the array I will loose that reference @kyler

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to change your structure and flatten your list, you can loop them dynamically, just use a function and call it within itself.

Here's an example using the `const list` you provided:

```
let found = false,
    loop = (items, filter) => {
        found = false;

        let results = items.filter(a => filter(a));
        if(results.length > 0) {
            found = true;
            return results;
        }

        if(!found && items && items.length > 0) {
            for(let i = 0; i < items.length && !found; i++) {
                if(items[i] && items[i].children && items[i].children.length > 0)
                    results = loop(items[i].children, filter);
            }
        }
        return results;
    };

let items = loop(list, item => item.id && item.id == "48");
```

In the example above we filter the list dynamically, iterating each and every item in the list and return the first item we find that matches a provided filter (2nd parameter).

You can use this to do pretty much whatever you'd like and can add arguments to add the menu "level" you're currently on, the parents, etc.

Note that this might get a bit slow if the list goes very deep, wrote it quickly and didn't tested outside of your provided list.

Ideally I would change the structure in order to make it easier to work with but if you must keep it this way, this works.

Answer (score 0):

You could find the object (without `children`) and get a flat array.

```js
const
    find = (array, title) => array.flatMap(({ children, ...o }) => [
        ...(o.title.includes(title) ? [o]: []),
        ...find(children, title)
    ]),
    list = [{ id: "41", title: "sample", children: [{ id: "42", title: "sample", children: [{ id: "43", title: "sample", children: [] }, { id: "44", title: "sample", children: [] }, { id: "45", title: "sample", children: [] }] }, { id: "46", title: "no sample", children: [{ id: "47", title: "sample", children: [] }, { id: "48", title: "sample", children: [] }] }] }, { id: "29", title: "sample", children: [{ id: "30", title: "sample", children: [] }, { id: "49", title: "no sample", children: [] }, { id: "31", title: "sample", children: [] }] }];

console.log(find(list, 'no sample'));
console.log(find(list, 'ample'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```